# Git hooks output & prompts in VSCode

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, githooks

I have problem with outputing git hook script to terminal in VSCode. I've set up pre-push hook which executes and prompts user to write in some details just like this:

```
$ git push
Pick from options: 

1) Major update
2) Minor update
4) Exit
```

Thing is, this works **only** if I use command line with "git push" command.
And what i want to achieve is that when you use VSCode source control button "sync changes" it will prompt user to input somewhere.
Currently it is stuck on syncing changes waiting for input.

The simplified pre-hook script looks like this

```
select type in "Major update" "Minor update" Exit
    do
        case $type in
            "Major update")
                MAJOR_NUMBER=$((MAJOR_NUMBER+1))
                break;;
            "Minor update")
                MINOR_NUMBER=$((MINOR_NUMBER+1))
                break;;
            "Exit")
                exit 1
                break;;
        esac
    done
# ..some more code..
```

I couldn't find any solution yet. I was thinking if there is some way to pop new terminal and prompt there but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I would recommend trying to find some other way to collect that information and/or reject in the case where it's missing -- usually interactive pre-push / pre-commit hooks are a smell

Comment: @AnthonySottile I think some kind of git hook inside remote repo like pre-receive would be better for this case? But i don't have access to remote repo directly, so I can't add anything like that. Unfortunately no other solution comes to my mind.. Well I wen't with disablind sync changes button so devs are forced to push through CLI.

Comment: i have the same issue as well, don't know which window the output from Git goes to.